# Get user data using access token in laravel passport client app

Tags: php, json, laravel, access-token, laravel-passport

I have successfully created **server.app** and **client.app** using **Laravel Passport documentation**. Everything works as expected.

**client.app Route:**

```
Route::get('callback', function (Request $request) {
   $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
   $response = $http->post('http://server.app/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => 3,
        'client_secret' => 'secret',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://client.app/callback',
        'code' => $request->code
    ]
   ]);
   return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
});
```

By default, this route returns **access_token**, with which i can do whatever i want.

**Request:**

```
http://server.app/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fclient.app%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=
```

**Returns:**

```
http://client.app/callback?code=access_token
```

**Question:**

How to make correct request to **server.app** with given access_token in **client.app** to get for example **user(s) email(s)**.

Should i use: `http://server.app/api/user` request to get data? If yes, how i can do that? If possible, please write a code.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've been going absolutely insane about this issue! It just made no freaking sense as to why it kept spitting out the stupid `Unauthenticated` error when trying to hit-up a route such as `/api/user`. After much searching (MUCH searching), I finally found the answer. If you see this fero from Laracasts, you're my hero!

> Did you check `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` ?
>
> in the `mapApiRoutes()` you can set the **middleware**. check to make sure
>   its `auth:api`. if its not, change it. also, remove the `auth`
>   **middleware** from the route `api.php` file.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-passport-api-unauthenticated-in-postman-using-personal-access-tokens

**Edit:**

Once you've made the change to the `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` mentioned above, proceed with the below example.

First things first, we need to retrieve a fresh `access_token`. To do this, I'm using the **password** `grant_type` (more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#password-grant-tokens)

To retrieve a fresh `access_token`, I've created a new route on `routes/web.php` and called it `/connect`. I've then placed the code from the above link into it:

```
Route::get('connect', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://example.com/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $request->client_id,
            'client_secret' => $request->client_secret,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => ''
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

Using [Chrome Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), you need to:

1. Set the method to `GET`
2. Enter the connect URL with the relevant params i.e. http://example.com/connect?client_id=1&client_secret=W2zogh7tiBh2jfHleYuzpViv7dqynDYQ6O07DKLj&username=test@test.com&password=123456
3. Click the **headers** tab (it's next to Authorization), add a key of `Accept` and value of `application/json`
4. Hit the Send button

**Example result:**

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 31535999,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImE0MmFiYjZkNTQ5M2ZjMGQxYzVmM2E3MDFlOTNjMTRlOTQxMTBmNWQ5NmI1ODI0NTBmMmEyM2MwMzQ5OTMwODdiZGUwYTI5ZDU5N2VjYTExIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYTQyYWJiNmQ1NDkzZmMwZDFjNWYzYTcwMWU5M2MxNGU5NDExMGY1ZDk2YjU4MjQ1MGYyYTIzYzAzNDk5MzA4N2JkZTBhMjlkNTk3ZWNhMTEiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTE0Njg4ODIsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MTQ2ODg4MiwiZXhwIjoxNTIzMDA0ODgxLCJzdWIiOiI3NWNlZDUwMC0xNTQ0LTExZTctOWE4ZS1hZDVmMWFlZTM4OWUiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.dV3DKDM7IN-oGnZ_Rw10VnYkh9ySlz5i859yO0roZLAYwgmsmEEZK_vpttudUoKmYenqibZQXg6HG4KHRd-cgas_2DpO-7UCkXQYNTriUUAQ4XM6To86EOaf2BW1a07kdVGXTdo_ETQc7heUG0NWQ8-Hrr2NHkSyDULupDs8gDg_fg6xSVsFUEDZB32UIGwquAHT1Y21ZpTdQar0Rag9qOLeZYTR05ro0v9_rQbSoDgJiZE3KT9GbqwU_BegWRmAwY6LmxG4raZpSMgqYEMo3D9D0lJiomOLK4pSjqmi0EVti04zZ6Vg4GHE6S1TgC6IlakV2bMItXTWuZT6T0jEba-3ctaC4K2T8F4P8J6t-99mKY-_zSwgfGm1FErK09qixJlZ4zFsCCT7MgNQVoyu7GkJdTJVlpL1QXLc1QhfrtW11a4gg4Nlja_VyRdB9fZHomgMLpvm_HvSlqEvpeWb8wGkCts9w7ivSNLim-LuFgswGNhTZZqLEbuwB6sJV-l1V0MJCq7_h0yTmLlBdoUkxCaDJJvkUSLk0MUaalAAzY1OCxm-tJcKn31m4yOwf25ZDWf8tWuOTKarEbFyxjB0elkxXQXGe7J7TJAg0tuIEQ8YTL3ExJQ6I7zwtCL83bPOWYRGlJrsX6Lsf0qB-xMVD2DzA3JKDKvZTp5x92kP821",
  "refresh_token": "ArOWW0glHjflLpL4fKOsrNUXT5v91u+CjwcE8LBvH7GJsaM0gWaFe8GH9zXjh8SHew+cg7v1IMiIPLYSVdf7h8oOeV7wgwjChI9YM0Kt6iE4wOXJuy0VwPSCj+danHDuWC3nJWYLrPydTE3h/jgFNjWEPfgXGLfiRWjWQMozddz5EWd4pvUI7J64Lw6cMCg/BslZLHtfN7IWoC1RQGp5K0cGO0QmZfsGMSzsoSUNFjv16BXiKSqlNvs5aGhxErFY4wEOKqBifXUkb3SwnK/iHKg3irmqj4fOf/aKNyCdd/PJCHrRPocrW83oM1sjq7eDufEIlgxmy7uRset8GLAWjx/n6rzkxz2QM0/9Lyc/XN9OL00XBYjA47a1wL55qUUUYWevaFwxWX8LG2UjBf9Vv2lfvLcBBkbgqpalePMDh6wb8IDyJek4BbvZtJ1VZ/l+A9XXY9rQt/hIDdoOAtib8CGr9/CERFIrByZa3TEJBCLAa2FvJSIhHVnKvnuvZX3e9qhTkgHqowJrWg2C3VyPDQYAdIhdpTEvs0pcGSAZWhwXfu9xKQOeyRTEScbLKQmuW+sGbwU+qfdLgh/BR5kW4TMer4TIzWKSuHsqmibgiUwaQkwTrtjH2Xz9Z9XmAbVzJ8pqbEZPe7t5whXDoRSnAwWymdxk2E7SiSsVUA3kX39="
}
```

Highlight the `access_token` string and copy it to a text editor.

You'll then need to create a new route in `routes/api.php`. The route below will simply output the current API users' info:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return response()->json(request()->user());
    });
});
```

Once you've done the above, make these changes to Postman:

1. Set the method to `GET`
2. Change the URL to point to the API route i.e. http://example.com/api/user
3. Click on the **headers** tab again and add a new key of `Authorization` and value of `Bearer access_token_here` (replace `access_token_here` with the access token you copied earlier)
4. Hit the Send button

**Example output:**

```
{
  "id": "75ced500-1544-11e7-9a8e-ad5f1aee389e",
  "name": "test test",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "created_at": "2017-03-30 23:29:03",
  "updated_at": "2017-03-30 23:29:03"
}
```

Comment: In my case, i ended up by giving each user a personal access token... did you tested your solution and is it working?

Comment: Tested it thoroughly and it's working 100%. Couldn't believe a simple swap on the middleware from `api` to `auth:api` on the RouteServiceProvider.php was all that was needed. Do you want me to add a completely detailed step by step using Chrome Postman as well so you can see everything?

Comment: Well, i understand your answer, but others might not understand it. Update your answer with example and i will aproove your answer and mark as correct one.

Comment: There we go matey! I think this should help quite a few people in the future.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Hope, anyone else will find this usefull. Accepted.

Comment: days passed! you are a savior man! now i get a clear view of how it's done!

Comment: @adamj This works, it also will create a new access_token every time you login, It is that ok? Your `oauth_access_tokens` will increase fast.

Answer (score 5):

According to Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#passing-the-access-token), you should add route to server app (`routes/api.php`): `$response->getBody();`

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    // authenticated user. Use User::find() to get the user from db by id
    return app()->request()->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Make request via quzzle:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: What did you get in the response body?

Comment: ``Client error: `GET http://server.app/api/user` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"Unauthenticated."}`` . I am using correct access token.

Comment: Also, i used ``$response = $client->get('http://server.app/api/user' ...`` and ``$client`` as ``new GuzzleHttp\Client;``

Comment: Now it gives: ``Server error: `GET http://server.app/api/user` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>``. I know, because of ``return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];``

Comment: correct access_token returns 500 error, not correct, returns ``Unauthenticated``.

Comment: where did the $accessToken came from?

Comment: @mpalencia it's returned in reply to authentication request

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running it on POSTMAN chrome app?
If not, download it. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Fill the information.
[image]

After you successfully generated the data, click the CODE button from the top-right (I highlighted it with green).

Lastly, select your language and copy the code. For PHP, I selected php cURL.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I tried all mentioned solutions but it remains same. Read so many tutorial and websites but didn't get the solution. Finally, **got the solution**: I am using laravel 8 and it has declared two packages for api request one is passport and other is sanctum. By default in `User` model it uses `use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;` for api token. If you use `Sanctum` package it's ok. If you don't use it (If you are using passport) then change the line from Sanctum to Passport as `use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;`

[image]