# Laravel Passport: Displayusername after successful login

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am currently using `Laravel 5.4` and I tried to deploy `Passport` for practice by following https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13 .  After successful authorization, it returns the `Json output` on the clients site. but Instead of  that I want to display the username with the welcome message** in another `view 'logged'`. The basic problem is to how to extract the username from the server. i have seen fb/twitter providing the basic user info,  I am trying to replicate that. 
Any Ideas how can I achieve that?
If any other info is required I can provide that
My web.php

```
    use Illuminate\HTTP\Request;

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });



    Route::get('/log', function () {
        $query = http_build_query ([
            'client_id' => 9,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8991/callback',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'scope' => '', ]);

        return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8081/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
        });


    Route::get('/callback', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

        $response = $http->post('http://127.0.0.1:8081/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => 9,
            'client_secret' => 'Y0XV42feEZ5xurwUwaAs46PzgvsLGoghUfgfRUId',
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8991/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
            ],

        ]);

            return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
            //return view('logged');

    });
```

Comment: `$user = Auth::user()->username;` Will get you the current logged in user name, provided username is the column name in your users table

Comment: @linktoahref will check

Comment: @linktoahref i am using passport to authorize the user. I have 'user' named column in users table so I am using return '$user = Auth::user()->user;' to display user name but it is showing **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17836382/5808894

Comment: @linktoahref I already checked that brother.  So according to that I can't use '$user = Auth::user()->user; in web.php  ?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746078/get-user-data-using-access-token-in-laravel-passport-client-app