# Laravel - return user and authentication details upon login

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

Completely new to Laravel and attempting to use Passport authentication to make a login call. The call returns user auth details:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 600,
    "access_token": "...",
    "refresh_token": "..."
}
```

But I would also like to get the user details in the same response:

```
 {
    "user_id": "1",
    "forename": "Mustafa",
    "surname": "3241234",
    "email": "mustafaaaa@gmail.com"
     ...
    "access_token": "...",
    "refresh_token": "..."
}
```

Is this possible? Here is my controller code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $params = [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $this->client->id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
        'username' => request('email'),
        'password' => request('password'),
        'scope' => '*'
    ];

    $request->request->add($params);

    $proxy = Request::create(
        'oauth/token',
        'POST'
    );

    return Route::dispatch($proxy);
}
```

Comment: there is a way. check this question and it's first answer 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746078/get-user-data-using-access-token-in-laravel-passport-client-app

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be okay, then you should send the token to retrieve the user details instead...
So you have something like this in your route file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::post('user', 'MyController@details');
    });
```

Then in your controller you have

```
public function details()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
```

Sure it helps...

Comment: thanks a lot this is exactly what i was trying to do. i thought i could send the user data with the access token but no luck with that