# Laravel: how to sign in via api.php routes?

Tags: php, laravel

In the below example, json `0: "if you read this you has been authenticated"` must be retrieved from server by http://example.loc/api/get_restricted_content/` request from HTTP client only if one who send request has been authorized.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/get_restricted_content', function(){
  return response()->json("if you read this you has been authenticated");
});
```

I don't know how to implement it, but I suppose we need to send email and password in get-parameter. But it is definitely not enough because of Laravel security. How I can solve above problem?

Comment: Itd quite unclear what you want! You want to know what are the request you have to send to the middleware? If it is so please check the  docs  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#via-middleware   . Please go through the link and the auth api middlwware method amd see what it is requesting

Comment: @Aniketh Saha, I am sorry for unclear question. First: can I get some content for authorized users only from non-Laravel app (e. g. HTTP-client)? Next: if "yes", how  I can authorize via non-Laravel app?

Comment: Why not create a user in the laravel app just for this purpose, log him in and retrieve data from special routes only he has access to?

Comment: @ka_lin, according the future application concept, certain content must be retrieved by desktop app from laravel website. However, the user of desktop application must be registered in above laravel-website and must to use his email and password to get the content.

Comment: Then sound like you would need a [token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) based implementation for 3-rd party apps

Comment: Yes you can get the content of the user through non laravel client you just have to make a get request to the  route to get the access token. The access token will be having the datas of the user for more clarification read this question and the first verified answer  link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746078/get-user-data-using-access-token-in-laravel-passport-client-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa   this will be helpfull for sure