# Laravel Passport get Unauthenticated response although I used a valid token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with Passport installed, every thing goes OK on localhost: sign-up, sign-in and all other functionalities, don't know why when I uploaded the project to the server I always get Unauthenticated error message.

so far, I can login and issue the access token, but when try using this token to access other routes it fails and shows the previous message.

All tests have done on Postman.

Note: when I inspected the request header I couldn't see the authorization parameter appear in the header !!

*******images***********

[login OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtisq.png)

[test authenticated route failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPzV2.png)

*******images***********

any help here,,,

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you run `php artisan passport:install`?

Comment: @Vandolph, Yes I already installed it, the weird thing that I can issue the access token from login request, but basically cant use this token to access other routes .. the attached images clarify the issue

Comment: Try to check this one sir, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746078/get-user-data-using-access-token-in-laravel-passport-client-app/42571484#42571484

Comment: i am also getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

If the passport keys, then your keys files for authenticating the tokens are not available on the server... In this case, you can migrate the keys under the storage dir (which might be a bad idea) or generate a new key using the artisan... I hope this helps...

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

For new new keys